# Table with absolute position not sizing

Tags: html

I would like an absolutely positioned table to have 15px between the sides of the table and the edges of the window but unless I specify a width for the table it just keeps sizing to the contents.

Setting `style="position:absolute; left:15px; right:15px"` gives me the desired behavior on a div but not a table.

Giving the table a `width="100%"` makes the table 100% of the window width then adds 15px to the sides resulting in a scroll bar and badly positioned table.

Simply giving the table a `width="95%"` and centering it does not result in a fixed amount of space to the sides when the window re-sizes.

The table is absolute as it needs to be at the bottom of the page.

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mLa7mLf5/2/)

This seems like I am missing something obvious but I just haven't been able to figure it out or find it on google yet.

Comment: use `width="100%"`  with `margin = 0`

Comment: @phiter-fernandes That would give me no space to the sides of the table.  I would like to have 15px to the left and right of the table as stated in the question.

Comment: Then put the table inside a div with `padding:15px`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CSS**

```
.absoluteFill {
  /*your styles*/
  margin:0;
  width:calc(100% - 30px);
}
```

Comment: Does exactly what i needed. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome! Calc a very helpfull function, since I discovered it I use it all the time.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
.absoluteFill {
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  right: 15px;
  width: calc(100% - 30px);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ou5rza6b/

calc browser supports http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc

Answer (score 1):

you have to change just css and it will be in .tblPosition class as follows:

```
.tblPosition {
    bottom: 15px;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.borderClass {
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid
}

.absoluteFill {
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  right: 15px;
  margin: 0;
  width: calc(100% - 30px); /*full width minus left and right*/
}

.tblPosition {
  bottom: 15px;
}

.divPosition {
  top: 15px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<table height="50%" class="borderClass absoluteFill tblPosition">
  <tr>
    <td>This is not what I want</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div class="borderClass absoluteFill divPosition">
  This is what I want
</div>
```

I hope this answer will help you